# IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my application there are 2 initializers: one extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, the other extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. When I tried to run the application, I got the an `IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present`

If I understand correctly, both the initializers tried to create their own `WebApplicationContext`. So I tried overriding the `createRootApplicationContext()` to force it to return null. Although the application did run with no exception, it ran incorrectly. Is there anyway to work around this?

**WebInitializer.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class, AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RepositoryConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer**

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;


public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess your repository configuration ( `RepositoryConfig.class` )  should be inside  `getRootConfigClasses` and not in `getServletConfigClasses`... could you please try that?

Comment: @kukkuz doesn't work, same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I'm not supposed to put a constructor in `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer`. The constructor will create a new ContextLoaderListener. Just remove that and everything works fine.